# How many addresses can be stored inside an address [ ] in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm building a contract that requires new users to send exactly 0.1 ether in order to enter an investment round.

I've been struggling with this for a while an I don't know how to store the addresses of new investors inside the contract so I can use the "address index" later.

For what I saw, dynamic arrays are not recommended because they can easily use "too much gas" and get the contract stuck forever.

- How can I know how many addresses can actually be stored inside **address [ ]** ?

I assume a simple test can be done but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is the code I'm using. It's based on the great [article](https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a) Rob Hitchens wrote.

```
address[] userIndex;    // New user address gets stored in dynamic array

function invest() public payable {  

    require(msg.value == 0.1 ether);    // checks if new investor sent 0.1 ether
    userIndex.push(msg.sender);        // adds new user to userIndex  

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no limit to how many items can be stored in a dynamic array. (Technically, there's a limit of 2^256, but that's on the order of how many atoms there are in the known universe.)

The number of items in the array doesn't affect gas usage at all. What *can* consume a lot of gas is *enumerating* a large array. (What matters in that case is that you're executing a lot of code by running a long loop.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I didn't understand what you mean about enumerating. I'm planning to create a loop that iterates over the address array in order like this:  for (uint i = 0; i < userIndex.length; i++). So it starts with the first investor address and then the second and so on.. will that be enumerated?

Comment: Yes, that's what enumeration means. Reading a value from storage costs 200 gas, and the current gas limit for a block is 8,000,000, so you wouldn't be able to do this at all past 40,000 addresses. And, of course, I assume you're going to do something with each address other than just look at it. E.g. if you modify a value in storage at each iteration, that's 5,000 gas, so 1,600 addresses would consume all the available gas for a block. It's generally better to avoid loops altogether. (Without knowing what you're doing, it's hard to suggest an alternative.)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know thanks a lot. I already voted and accepted your answer but it doesnt appear because im under 15 of reputation. I'm actually trying to build a dapp based on a real world system called "abundance flower" where investors get 8X what they invested. The thing is that is a ponzi scheme in real life, I want to make a dapp that is not. So im looking for ways to evolve the idea based on what can I do on blockchain. It would mean a lot to me if you want to read more about it here: https://github.com/ianbritto/EIGTH

Comment: If you could somehow know the expected offset of the user, you could jump to that location in address. Do you have some link that describes this I could look at..or is that just a hash?